# Swift delegate.

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

In Objective-C I can make something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SomeCustomProtocol> someObject;
```

How to make this in swift? 
I tried this:

```
let someObject: AnyObject, SomeCustomProtocol = ....;
```

And it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to declare a delegate in Swift is:

```
weak var delegate: SomeCustomDelegate?
```

Swift uses ARC for memory management hence it's still susceptible to retain cycles.

Read a [good reference](http://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/05/demystifying-retain-cycles-in-arc/?utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_197&utm_source=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly) to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like :

```
 var delegate: SomeCustomProtocol?
```

Find more guidance from [here](http://codewithchris.com/learn-swift-from-objective-c-part3/)

Comment: This is incorrect, it will keep a strong reference to a delegate object.

Answer (score 2):

```
let someObject:SomeCustomProtocol = ....;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to take in consideration when creating a delegate property is:

- Use the weak keyword to avoid retain cycles
- Set the property as an optional type of your protocol

for example:

```
//Protocol
protocol SomeProtocolDelegate: class {
func doSomething()
}

weak var delegate: SomeProtocolDelegate?
```

Here is a more complete and very useful implementation.

https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef#.vvdx9admt